# NHibernate Collection Left Outer Join Where Clause Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, nhibernate

It seems that when using the following NHibernate query, I do not get a root entity when the left outer join has no records.

```
ICriteria critera = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Entity));

criteria.CreateCriteria("SubTable.Property", "Property", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

criteria.Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("Property", value)));
```

The SQL that I am trying to generate is:

```
SELECT * FROM BaseTable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM SubTable
    WHERE Property <> value
)Sub ON Sub.ForeignKey = BaseTable.PrimaryKey
```

Notice that the where clause is inside the left join's select statement. That way if there arent any maching sub records, we still get a top level record. It seems like NHibernate is producing the following SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM BaseTable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM SubTable
)Sub ON Sub.ForeignKey = BaseTable.PrimaryKey
WHERE Sub.Property <> value
```

Is there anyway to achieve that first piece of SQL? I have already tried:

```
ICriteria critera = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Entity));

criteria.CreateCriteria("SubTable.Property", "Property", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

criteria.Add(
    Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Expression.IsNull("Property"))
        .Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("Property", value)));
```

I am looking for a solution using the Criteria API.

Comment: You might take a look at the nhibernate log file and see what sql statement is being issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**this**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins):

```
var hql = @"select bt
            from BaseTable bt
                left join bt.SubTable subt
                    with subt.Property <> :property";
```

Or perhaps:

```
var hql = @"select bt
            from BaseTable bt
                left join bt.SubTable subt
                    where subt.ForeignKey = bt.PrimaryKey
                        and subt.Property <> :property";
```

Finally:

```
var result = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                    .SetParameter("property", "whateverValue")
                    .List<BaseTable>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use nHibernate but I think this is the SQL you need to generate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BaseTable 
LEFT JOIN SubTable sub
 ON Sub.ForeignKey = BaseTable.PrimaryKey and  sub.Property <> value
```

What you want isn;t a where clasue but an additional condition on the join. Hope that helps.

Comment: very true... I didn't even consider that.

Comment: This explains why: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: I understand the problem, I guess I was looking for how to solve it using the NHibernate Criteria API. Thanks!